# How to install the latest possible version of an npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

How do I install the latest available version of an npm package?  '@latest' sure doesn't fetch the latest - I assume it means the latest stable or something.

I've been using a hack for a while because I cannot seem to find any info on this:

```
npm i extract-text-webpack-plugin@X
```

The 'X' causes it to fail and dump all possible versions where I then copy and paste the correct one instead of the 'X'. Kinda ridiculous.

I've tried 3rd party packages like 'latest-version' but they all fail to get the very latest version.

There doesn't seem to be an official to do this.  For example at the time of writing the latest version of *extract-text-webpack-plugin* is *2.0.0-beta.4*. However doing:

```
npm i extract-text-webpack-plugin@latest
```

Will install '1.0.1'

I can see the latest version by doing

```
npm info pkg versions --json (without --json it will cut off when there are many versions)
```

For lack of an actual tool I guess its going to be some grep work.

Comment: Why in the world would this be downvoted. How about an answer to a very clear question? About to leave this trolled website.

Comment: https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version [`1.0.1`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin) *is* the 'latest' version of that package - published to the npm registry at least ([tagged](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag) as `latest`)

From the docs for [`cli/dist-tag`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag). Emphasis mine.

> Tags can be used to provide an alias instead of version numbers.
>
> For example, a project might choose to have multiple streams of development and use a different tag for each stream, e.g., stable, beta, dev, canary.
>
> By default, the latest tag is used by npm to identify the current version of a package, and npm install  (without any @ or @ specifier) installs the latest tag. **Typically, projects only use the latest tag for stable release versions, and use other tags for unstable versions such as prereleases**.
>
> By default, other than latest, no tag has any special significance to npm itself.

If you want the [beta releases](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/releases), then install from GitHub, or use the tags explicitly.

```
$ npm install webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
```

This is made pretty clear by [reading the manual.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Even more clear:

`latest` is an *implicit* tag, attached to any published version of a package that was **not** published with an *explicit* tag (`--tag`).

Installing `xyz@latest` simply looks up the release *tagged* as `latest` in the registry. In the case of this package, that's release `1.0.1`. **That's it**. There's nothing special going on here. **`@latest` does not pull the most recent version published to `npm`**

The versions listed as betas were tagged differently. Obviously none of them were tagged as `latest`, so trying to use `@latest` to get one is pointless.

From the registry:

```
'dist-tags': { latest: '1.0.1', beta: '2.0.0-beta.4' }
```

Again, use the GitHub releases for the bleeding edge, or use the versions/tags explicitly.

```
$ npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin@beta
```

Here you go, made especially for you:

- [`recent-version`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recent-version)
- [`recent-version-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recent-version-cli)

Condense this into a shell script, and you're good to go:

```
$ npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin@$(recent-version extract-text-webpack-plugin)
```

Comment: Except the latest version available through npm is `2.0.0-beta.4` which can be installed by specifying that version implicitly. And as you can see @latest will not fetch that version. The fact that npm will list `2.0.0-beta.4` clearly implies that its aware of the version.  I feel its making it extra difficult to fetch it though.

Comment: Despite my last comment getting deleted, I'm going to reiterate: You need to read the manual more carefully. I feel like a broken record trying to explain this to you. Being tagged as `latest` does not mean it is the most recently published version.

Comment: That last shell script is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `npm update` as long as you have the package installed:

```
npm update <package>
```

Comment: Huh.. No. First of all the question is about installing and secondly `update` has the exact same issue. It will not update to the very latest. Thanks though.

Comment: No errors. Asking if I have overlooked something in the documentation. As far as I can tell its not possible which seems odd.

Comment: Try running `npm uninstall extract-text-webpack-plugin` then run `npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin` and see what happens.