# Managing javascript dependencies

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, deck.gl

I am using Yarn. I have a project that needs the latest developments of the deck.gl project (i.e. something that has not yet released).
I tried:

1- To clone the repo, build it and publish the different modules in a registries but I (legitimately) do not own the @deck.gl scope - so it seems that route is not possible.

2- To clone the repo, build it and then add the various module directories to my project using:

```
yarn add file:/Users/alleon_g/0x-TechWork/deck.gl/modules/core/
```

but that seems to create issues with dependencies of that module

```
yarn add v1.13.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "luma.gl@^7.0.0-alpha.14" required by "file:/Users/alleon_g/0x-TechWork/deck.gl/modules/core/" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

What is the proper way of using the latest modules of a project that has not yet published its components?

Guillaume

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650856/how-to-install-the-latest-possible-version-of-an-npm-package

tldr; use `@latest`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry if my question was not clear enough but it is not about fetching the latest version of a (npm) package.
It is about using the latest code on github when there are commits that you need to use and when the project has not yet release a newer verion of the packages (including those fixes)

Comment: Then use github link as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly

Comment: You're using npm syntax in Yarn... Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411864/how-to-install-package-from-github-repo-in-yarn

Comment: Same error with yarn syntax - (invalid package version undefined). I usually do a: yarn add @deck.gl/core

It seems to me that this is not working for a repo hosting several modules.

Comment: Hm, interesting, maybe they didn't post a release or something like that.. Can't help you here, sorry!